# Can a 450 V AC starter motor film capacitor bear 300V DC?

Tags: capacitor, ac, dc, maximum-ratings

I know AC and DC ratings for capacitor differ. But when it comes to film (polyester) capacitors and more in general non polarised capacitors, I ask myself if, given only the AC rating, it is possible/safe to use them in low current (<< 1mA @ 600V) DC applications.

In my case, I am building a one stage [voltage multiplier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_multiplier) and I need a capacitor (C1) rated to bear a steady state 320 V DC (since Us is 230V AC) and an initial charging transient under AC. I initially used electrolitic capacitors (10 series 63V 100 uF) and it works fine, however I wonder whether repeated turn on transients may damage the polarized electrolitic capacitors. I decided to try with a polyester capacitor used in AC single phase motors however I am having second thoughts on its ability to withstand DC.

So, in your opinion, is a 450V AC rated capacitor suited for C1 in this application?

PS: This is a test installation used in a controlled environment.

Additional info:

- Low power application << 1 mA at 600V DC.
- Mostly turned on and off a few times a day for a week.
- Source is 230V isolated from mains using a dedicated insulation transformer

Datasheet is [here](https://www.conrad.com/p/weltron-wb40200a-1-pcs-mkp-motor-capacitor-connector-clips-20-f-450-v-ac-5-x-h-40-mm-x-71-mm-441673) (in download section. There is no mention of DC rating.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a link to the data sheet?

Comment: In general, metallized polypropylene "motor" capacitors are some of the toughest caps available. The only way to know if it will survive however (long-term) is to look at it's DC rating in it's datasheet.

Comment: Entschuldigung, I forgot. Here you can find the required datasheet @vini_i https://www.conrad.com/p/weltron-wb40200a-1-pcs-mkp-motor-capacitor-connector-clips-20-f-450-v-ac-5-x-h-40-mm-x-71-mm-441673

Comment: @rdtsc I did it. There is no DC rating. If there were a DC rating I would not have asked.